# Electron Developer Tools (copy/cut/paste not working)

Tags: javascript, electron

I updated the version of Electron to 3.0.2, and now cut/copy/paste not working in Developer Tools, but work in Application.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem in Electron 3.0.2; it is fixed in the latest version 3.0.4.

While the keyboard shortcuts for cut/copy/paste didn't work indeed in 3.0.2, it was still possible to select them directly with the mouse from the standard Edit menu (provided there is one)...

Comment: But I've noticed when you use 2 displays you can face that very issue. This is when the developer tools are on a separate display.